# Is SpamAssassin sensitive against UTF-8 words?

Tags: email, mail-server, spamassassin

let me explain with a simple example:

An email with **Order** in its subject will trigger SPAM filters such as SpamAssassin.

I want to know if an email subject contains that words translation in Arabic: **أطلب** or in Persian: **سفارش**, Does it draw attentions too?

Comment: if those words are in the filter database, then yes, the email should be flagged.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, How can I check? Is it possible to manually change the database contents?